# IWshShell3 Error VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am running a program through my VB code in excel, which writes into command prompt some commands , and i get that error .
I searched all the internet, but nothing seems like my error.
Here is the part of code where i am getting the error:

```
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BaseStation" & i).Cells(7, intcol) <> "" Then
   Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   oShell.Run ("telnet -f C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\output.log " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BaseStation" & i).Cells(3, intcol))
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))

   Set ObjFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set objFile = ObjFS.GetFile("C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\output.log")
   Set ts = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I have to mention that this program is running just fine on my other computer, and after all my investigations, I figured out that the difference between this computers is that on this one(the one with the error) has a 32 bit excel, while the other one(the one that is running the application without errors) has 64 bit excel.
The problem is that this application must run in 32 bit excel too.

Comment: What is the username at this point?

Comment: The username right now is "Claud".

Comment: FYI something like `oShell.Run commandString, 0, True` will wait until the command is finished running so you don't have to do application.wait  (Because how do you know when it will finish? What if it doesn't finish within that time?)

Comment: What is the error and on what line?

Comment: It still doesn't works, @CodyG .

Comment: Wasn't meant to be a solution, just a note that may save you from more future problems.

Comment: Does the computer with 32bit have the `telnet ` command?

Comment: Yes, it has the command

Comment: I tried to install office 64 bit on the computer where I had the error and it works just fine. So, why I have an error on 32 bits office?

Comment: It's possible that 32-bit is running the command as a 32-bit command prompt or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of the error, so I will explain it, just in case someone else deals with this problem.
So, windows has 2 types of command prompts, one for 64 bits programs, and one for 32 bits.
When you activate telnet, it only activates the feature for 64 bits.
Because I used 32 bits Office, it was trying to access the 32 bits cmd, which hadn't the telnet feature active, so I found a solution : copying "telnet.exe" from C:/Windows/Sysyem32 to C:/Windows/SysWOW64 .
By doing this, you will be able to use telnet from 32 bits command prompt.